# Change Symbol Visibility in Object File or Library ('t' -> 'T')

Tags: c, shared-libraries, visibility, symbols, binutils

I need to change the symbol visibility in an object file or library. For example, a particular shared object has a symbol name present, but its local so I can't bind to it (the lower `t` indicates local in the TEXT section):

```
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so | grep -i OPENSSL_cpuid_setup
00000000000c3f80 t OPENSSL_cpuid_setup
000000000008a360 t fips_openssl_cpuid_setup
```

The same symbol is present in the archive, but the archive not being used in this project (the upper `T` indicates global in the TEXT section):

```
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a | grep -i OPENSSL_cpuid_setup
0000000000000310 T OPENSSL_cpuid_setup
000000000000f8e0 T fips_openssl_cpuid_setup
```

I'd like the visibility of `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup` to be global rather than local.

Is there a way to change the symbol visibility in a object file or library? I've been through [Binutil tools](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), and it does not look like there's a suitable tool.

And for completeness, the 'easiest' methods are *not* available because the source code is sequestered and cannot be changed. The easiest methods include (1) removing `static` from the declaration; and (2) using GCC's visibility attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You could try (untested) `objcopy` with the `--globalize-symbol` option. However, this is only going to work with the archive, not the dynamic library, as you can modify the normal symbol table and not the (hashed) dynamic symbol table.

A disgusting hack would be to determine the offset of the routine from a global (using objdump and writing it to a file from your makefile), then create a function pointer, then jump to that (yuck).